# How do I download a set of files from s3 using ios?

Tags: ios, ios4, amazon-s3, ios-simulator, download

I've seen a lot of questions on SO answering this but yet I'm having trouble getting the implementation right because the files aren't downloading.

Some background is that I have a set of 10 files in s3. I can see them np through an S3ListObjectsResult. I'm then storing that result in a filtered NSMutableArray s3Result. That's all working fine.

Later, I actually want to download the files, and so I tried doing this:

In the .h file:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <AmazonServiceRequestDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *s3Objects;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *s3Results;
```

In the .m file:

```
AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:key withSecretKey:secret];
for (NSString *result in s3Results) {
    S3GetObjectRequest *s3Request = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:s3Result withBucket:bucket];
    s3Request.delegate = self;
    S3GetObjectResponse *s3Response = [s3 getObject:s3Request];
    [s3Objects addObject:[[NSData alloc] initWithData:s3Response.body]];
```

This compiles fine and runs ok, but "downloads" the files much too quickly to actually be working and in fact self.s3Objects returns a count of 0.

1. Is there a way to see debugging on S3's side?
2. What am I doing wrong with regards to getting the files?
3. Is there a chance that this is because I am doing this from within the XCode simulator?

EDIT:
Ok, so I added in some methods that AWS needs, namely didCompleteWithResponse, didReceiveData, didFailWithError, and didFailWithServiceException.

The result is that the files are being downloaded now (I can print out the response.body and see data) but they aren't being added to s3Objects:

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response
{
   [self.s3Objects addObject:[[NSData alloc] initWithData:response.body]];
}
```

The count on self.s3Objects always returns 0 even after this.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working. The answer to the original question was to implement the missing AWS methods. The answer to the second question was that I had missed initializing the s3Objects array. After doing that, it works well.